# Why is this function not a valid PDF?

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

My text book says that the following function is not a valid PDF:

[image]
[image]

According to my calculation this could be a PDF if $k=3/2$

I applied integration to $f(x)$ between $1$ and $3$, and found $3/2$.

Why is this function not a valid PDF?

What am I missing here?

Comment: According to my calculations, $f(x)$ changes sign when $x$ passes through $x=2$.  Valid pdfs are never negative, but this function is.

Comment: A pdf is a non-negative function whose integral is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be this. Fixing a k, you can define your PDF. So if you show that for every k, there exists an interval I in [1,3] where your integration is negative ($\int_{A}{kx(x-2)}dx = P_{k}(X \in A)<0$), that pdf is not a density because the probability of an event could not be negative. So if k<0 then I=[2,3], if k>0 then I=[1,2].
You have just calculated the k for which your integral is 1, that in general is not sufficient for defining a PDF.